# how to upgrade tinyMCE to its newer version?

Tags: editor, tinymce, upgrade, text-editor

I am using `tinyMCE 3.2.6` and it is not working properly on `IE 9` and above. So I thought of upgrading it to 3.5.5

when I downloaded new version of tinyMCE 3.5.5 I saw the are all similar files like tinyMCE 3.2.6 but only difference is a file name `tiny_mce_src.js` is in newer version but `tiny_mce_cp.js` is on old version.

Again a twist is, contents of `tiny_mce_src.js`( new version) is similar to `tiny_mce.js` ( old version).

Now please let me know how to upgrade it to newer version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to overwrite the old files with the new files (even though you think nothing has changed!).